# How to store array values in an environment variable in Postman

Tags: arrays, api, testing, automated-tests, postman

I am using a postman to automate apis.

Now I am using following request , lets say :-

```
{
  "customerId": "{{currentClientId}}"
}
```

Where clientid is a dynamic variable whose value is substituted dynamically as 1 , 2, 3,4 so on..
I call this request multiple times using setNextRequest call in this eg lets say 10.This is being done using a counter variable. I am initialising the counter in my previous request to 0 and using for loop with value as counter as 10 calling the request 10 times.There is no response in body just successful http code 204.

I want to store all these clientids coming in request into an environment Client array variable so I wrote a following **pre-request scrip**t:-

```
counter = pm.environment.get("counter");
ClientArray = pm.environment.get("ClientArray");
ClientArray.push(pm.environment.get("currentClientId"));
pm.environment.set("ClientArray",ClientArray);
```

In **Test Script**, wrote following code :-

```
counter = pm.environment.get("counter");

if(counter<=10) {
    console.log("hi");
    postman.setNextRequest("Request");
    counter++;
    pm.environment.set("counter",counter);
    console.log("Counter",counter);
}
```

The above scipts is throwing 
TypeError | ClientArray.push is not a function.

Could someone please advice how to achieve this.

Comment: Are you using this in the runner? How does the setNextRequest command know that there are 10 different ids? Is that _all_ the code you have in the pre-request? What does the actual response body look like? You need to provide more details if you want someone to help you out with this question.

Comment: Added some more details , Hope this gives sufficient information.

Answer (score 4):

When you retrieve a value from an environment variable like you're doing:

```
ClientArray = pm.environment.get("ClientArray");
```

You're not getting an array, you're getting a string which is why you're getting that error. You need to treat the variable like a string, append the `currentClientId` much like you do for the counter. Something like:

```
var currentClientIds = pm.environment.get("ClientArray");
currentClientIds = currentClientIds + "," + currentClientId
```

When you're done appending i.e. out of your loop simply take the string and convert it to an array:

```
var currentClientIds = pm.environment.get("ClientArray");
var idsArr = curentClientIds.split(',');
```